# Modify GSM DATA in ios

Tags: ios, networking, encryption, gsm

I'm looking to encrypt GSM data (not VOIP), i post [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13529101/intercept-gsm-data-in-ios), i read links posted, i can compile and run the application in a device.(jailbreak mode).

The main questions:

1. Can i encrypt GSM voice data ?
2. Can i send encrypted data over the GSM network ?
3. if yes, can i decrypt it again, i mean phone/network,when sending, will modify the structure of data or not?

Just to clarify, for now i can't find how to get the GSM data to encrypt, but i want to know if what i'm working in can be done before i spend time and effort.

I'm looking for an iOS/network expert :)
thank you.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Custom encrypt GSM calls](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13787251/custom-encrypt-gsm-calls)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Voice data is compressed/decompressed using different lossy codecs on the way from your phone to the second party. So, I don't see any way to successfully encrypt and decrypt it in 'well known way'. 
Probably, there are some techniques on adding some noise and filtering it out on the other side, but I'm not sure about their security.

Comment: Thank you, to resume you say that it's not possible to do it because network modify voice data after 'getting out' from the phone(this will be really hard to avoid).
I will see if other expert :) have suggestion about this, thank you Nickolay.